# Render a specific piece of dynamic data from the database by ID

Tags: javascript, react-redux, axios, mern

I am working on a table of client information. This application will allow the user to add, delete, edit, and view details of each client. So far I have most of it set up, but the problem I am running into at this moment is that when I have more than 1 client in the list, each "edit" or "detail" button that is rendered, when clicked, opens up modals for each and every listing. How can I isolate one listing to the modal instead? I was thinking of using the filter method, but I am unsure if I should build a completely new action that populates the input fields with that information or not. To minimize code, I am only going to give the "edit" example as the process should be very similar for the "detail" button as well.

**ClientEditModal.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  Button,
  Modal,
  ModalHeader,
  ModalBody,
  Form,
  FormGroup,
  Label,
  Input,
} from "reactstrap";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { editClient } from "../actions/clientActions";
import { openEditModal } from "../actions/modalActions";
import { closeEditModal } from "../actions/modalActions";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

class ClientEditModal extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.editClient();
  }

  toggle = () => {
    if (this.props.modal.isEditModalOpen) this.props.closeEditModal();
    else this.props.openEditModal();
  };

  onChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };

  onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    // Close modal
    this.toggle();
  };

  displayClient = (clients, _id) => {
    return (
      <FormGroup key={_id} timeout={500} classNames="fade">
        <Label for="name"> Name </Label>
        <Input
          type="text"
          name="name"
          id="client"
          value={clients.name}
          onChange={this.onChange}
        ></Input>

        <Label for="email"> Email </Label>
        <Input
          type="text"
          name="email"
          id="client"
          value={clients.email}
          onChange={this.onChange}
        ></Input>

        <Label for="number"> Number </Label>
        <Input
          type="text"
          name="number"
          id="number"
          value={clients.number}
          onChange={this.onChange}
        ></Input>

        <Button color="dark" style={{ marginTop: "2rem" }} block>
          Submit Client Edit
        </Button>
      </FormGroup>
    );
  };

  render() {
    const { clients } = this.props.client;
    return (
      // Split button into separate component
      <div>
        <Modal
          isOpen={this.props.modal.isEditModalOpen}
          toggle={this.toggle}
          style={{ padding: "50px" }}
        >
          <ModalHeader toggle={this.toggle}> Edit</ModalHeader>
          <ModalBody>
            <Form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
              {clients.map(this.displayClient)}
            </Form>
          </ModalBody>
        </Modal>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ClientEditModal.propTypes = {
  editClient: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  client: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  client: state.client,
  modal: state.modal,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
  editClient,
  openEditModal,
  closeEditModal,
})(ClientEditModal);
```

**modalActions.js**

```
import {
  OPEN_EDIT_MODAL,
  CLOSE_EDIT_MODAL,
  OPEN_DETAILS_MODAL,
  CLOSE_DETAILS_MODAL,
} from "./types";

export const openEditModal = () => {
  return {
    type: OPEN_EDIT_MODAL,
    modal: true,
  };
};

export const closeEditModal = () => {
  return {
    type: CLOSE_EDIT_MODAL,
    modal: false,
  };
};

export const openDetailsModal = () => {
  return {
    type: OPEN_DETAILS_MODAL,
    modal: true,
  };
};

export const closeDetailsModal = () => {
  return {
    type: CLOSE_DETAILS_MODAL,
    modal: false,
  };
};
```

**modalReducer.js**

```
import {
  OPEN_EDIT_MODAL,
  CLOSE_EDIT_MODAL,
  OPEN_DETAILS_MODAL,
  CLOSE_DETAILS_MODAL,
} from "../actions/types";

const initialState = {
  isEditModalOpen: false,
  isDetailsModalOpen: false,
};

export default function (state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case OPEN_EDIT_MODAL:
      return {
        ...state,
        isEditModalOpen: true,
      };
    case CLOSE_EDIT_MODAL:
      return {
        ...state,
        isEditModalOpen: false,
      };
    case OPEN_DETAILS_MODAL:
      return {
        ...state,
        isDetailsModalOpen: true,
      };
    case CLOSE_DETAILS_MODAL:
      return {
        ...state,
        isDetailsModalOpen: false,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

**clientActions.js**

```
import axios from "axios";
import {
  GET_CLIENTS,
  DELETE_CLIENT,
  ADD_CLIENT,
  CLIENTS_LOADING,
  EDIT_CLIENT,
  SET_CURRENT_EDIT_CLIENT,
} from "./types";

export const getClients = () => (dispatch) => {
  dispatch(setClientsLoading());
  axios.get("/api/clients").then((res) =>
    dispatch({
      type: GET_CLIENTS,
      payload: res.data,
    })
  );
};

export const addClient = (client) => (dispatch) => {
  axios.post("/api/clients", client).then((res) =>
    dispatch({
      type: ADD_CLIENT,
      payload: res.data,
    })
  );
};

export const deleteClient = (id) => (dispatch) => {
  axios.delete(`/api/clients/${id}`).then((res) =>
    dispatch({
      type: DELETE_CLIENT,
      payload: id,
    })
  );
};

export const setClientsLoading = () => {
  return {
    type: CLIENTS_LOADING,
  };
};

export const editClient = (id) => (dispatch) => {
  axios.put(`/api/clients/${id}`).then((res) =>
    dispatch({
      type: EDIT_CLIENT,
      payload: res.data,
    })
  );
};

export const setClientToEdit = (id) => (dispatch) => {
  dispatch({
    type: SET_CURRENT_EDIT_CLIENT,
    payload: id,
  });
};
```

**clientReducer.js**

```
import {
  GET_CLIENTS,
  DELETE_CLIENT,
  ADD_CLIENT,
  CLIENTS_LOADING,
  EDIT_CLIENT,
  VIEW_CLIENT,
  SET_CURRENT_EDIT_CLIENT,
} from "../actions/types";

const initialState = {
  clients: [],
  loading: false,
};

export default function (state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_CLIENTS:
      return {
        ...state,
        clients: action.payload,
        loading: false,
      };
    case DELETE_CLIENT:
      return {
        ...state,
        clients: state.clients.filter(
          (client) => client._id !== action.payload
        ),
      };
    case ADD_CLIENT:
      return {
        ...state,
        clients: [action.payload, ...state.clients],
      };
    case CLIENTS_LOADING:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: true,
      };
    case EDIT_CLIENT:
      return {
        ...state,
        clients: [action.payload, ...state.clients],
      };
    case VIEW_CLIENT:
      return {
        ...state,
      };
    case SET_CURRENT_EDIT_CLIENT:
      return {
        ...state,
        clientToEdit: state.clients.filter(
          (client) => client._id === action.payload
        )[0],
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```